# How do I search for a list of values in Excel and then export those to a list?

Tags: excel, windows, find, full-text-search, xlsx

I have a large excel spreadsheet that tracks some important folder locations. However, it is very large, and I would like to devise a solution that can be automated. Essentially I am looking for a server name, let's call it "\SERVER" for this example. I run ctrl-f and then enter "\SERVER" in the box, and click "Find All" which gives me all the information I need, but then there is no way to copy and paste this information. Is there an alternate way of doing this?

Comment: You will have to use VBA(macro) to search all the data using looping and export the data to separate sheet or external file as per the requirement.

Comment: may be you can do this in notepad++ with regex

Comment: The best solution I've found so far is to filter by a column and then copy/paste to a new spreadsheet, filter by the other column, and then copy and paste to a new spreadsheet.